# Converting a list to an array for a web service

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I'm currently trying to convert my searchList in the web app from a list to an array so that it can be consumed in the web method. Right now, I'm using a web reference which only allows arrays to be passed and returned. I'd like to just simply convert the list to an array, but it looks like that won't work. I've tried looking online but each scenario I've found hasn't been similar enough to where I'm able to solve this. Any idea on the best way to do this?

Web App

```
Protected Function SearchCustomer()
    Dim searchList As List(Of prxCustomerWebService1.Customer)
    Dim objCustomerWS As New prxCustomerWebService1.CustomerWS

    searchList = Cache("CustomerData")
    'arr = searchList.ToArray
    If (ddlSearchSpecs.Text = "Contains") Then
        searchList = objCustomerWS.GetContains(tbSearch.Text, ddlSearchFields.Text, searchList)
    ElseIf (ddlSearchSpecs.Text = "Starts With") Then
        searchList = objCustomerWS.GetStartsWith(tbSearch.Text, ddlSearchFields.Text, searchList)
    Else
        searchList = objCustomerWS.GetExact(tbSearch.Text, ddlSearchFields.Text, searchList)
    End If
    If searchList.Count = 0 Then
        lMessage.Text = "No Customers Found"
    End If
    Return searchList
End Function
```

Web Method

```
<WebMethod(description:="Gets customers that contain a specific value")> _
Public Function GetContains(ByVal sStringContains As String, ByVal sPropertyName As String, ByVal oListOfCustomers List(Of Customer))
    oListOfCustomers()
    Return CustomerFactory.GetContains(sStringContains, sPropertyName, oListOfCustomers)
End Function
```

Logic

```
  Public Shared Function GetContains(ByVal sStringContains As String, ByVal sPropertyName As String, ByVal oListOfCustomers As List(Of Customer))
    Dim oCustomerData As New CustomerData
    Dim oNewListOfCustomers As New List(Of Customer)
    Dim iIndex As Integer
    Dim propertyInfo As PropertyInfo

    propertyInfo = GetType(Customer).GetProperty(sPropertyName)

    If IsNothing(oListOfCustomers) = False AndAlso oListOfCustomers.Count > 0 Then
        Try
            For iIndex = 0 To oListOfCustomers.Count - 1
                If (propertyInfo.GetValue(oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex)).ToString.Trim.ToLower.Contains(sStringContains.ToLower) = True) Then
                    oNewListOfCustomers.Add(oListOfCustomers.Item(iIndex))
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return True
        End Try
    End If
    Return oNewListOfCustomers
End Function
```

Comment: Did you try `searchList.ToArray()`?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't seem to work in my setting. My bad, should have stated that.

Comment: `searchList.ToArray()` doesn't work how?  Do you get an error?  Do you get  nothing?

Comment: @Tim Well once I change it to searchList.ToArray() that's not a problem anywhrer, but when it passes to the web method, I'm not sure how to appropriately call it as an array, as well as convert the array back to the list so that it can pass to the logic method as a list

Comment: @Tim I converted the list to an array, but now the parameter in my webmethod is given me an error saying "You must implement a default accessor on System.Array because it inherits from ICollection." This is because I changed the parameter value from a "oListOfCustomers List(Of Customer)" to "ByVal arrayOfCustomers As Array". Not sure how to fixed it yet.

Comment: Don't declare it as type `Array`.  Declare it as type `Customer()`, which is a `Customer` array.  `Array` is the base type for all array objects and should rarely be used other than to access its `Shared` members.